# Jenkins Master on Linux to trigger PowerShell script on windows slave

Tags: jenkins

I have a Linux server where I have installed Jenkins and I have a windows slave server too. Just wanted to know is it possible to run powershell task from windows slave as we have Jenkins installed on Linux server? Or do I need to make a windows master to run all these powershell tasks?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Make sure that you select the appropriate slave (using label expressions) to execute the job.